# Compile and Run with highly-optimized fork of ANTLR 4

Tags: compilation, antlr, antlr4

How do i Compile and Run my grammar with highly-optimized fork of ANTLR 4
[highly-optimized ANTLR4](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. The question may be too specific and only applicable to the repository you link in github.

Have you tried the steps in the repository documentation, and if those did not work open an issue there?

Answer (score 1):

You can get both complete and runtime jar files here: [ANTLR 4 Tool](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.tunnelvisionlabs)

Compilation and running is the same as with the original ANTLR4, just replace the original files with new ones.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @pavel-smirnovm

Comment: When i try to compile with runtime jar it shows no main manifest attribute, in antlr4-runtime-4.7.3.jar

Comment: You have to compile with complete jar. Runtime, as its name says, is a short version of the complete jar with classes required only at runtime.

Comment: Ohh okay... Thanks

Comment: Which one is the complete jar in [ANTLR 4 Tool](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.tunnelvisionlabs)

Comment: http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4/4.7.3/ The one called antlr4-4.7.3-complete.jar